# Can't disable the system keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am trying to disable the system keyboard shortcuts with following code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Carbon/Carbon.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

void *oldHotKeyMode;

@synthesize window = _window;

-(void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
oldHotKeyMode = PushSymbolicHotKeyMode(kHIHotKeyModeAllDisabled);
}

-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
PopSymbolicHotKeyMode(oldHotKeyMode);
}

@end
```

But it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in System Preferences. This code works only if you checked "Enable access for assistive devices" in "Universal Access".